# Using HTML5 Audio in Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, html, this

When I run the following...

```
var obj = {
    array: ['1.mp3', '2.mp3', '3.mp3'],
    audio: new Audio(this.array[0])
};
```

...I get an error saying that it cannot read property '0' of undefined. However, when I run the following...

```
var obj = {
    array: ['1.mp3', '2.mp3', '3.mp3'],
};

var audio = new Audio(this.obj.array[0]);
```

...everything runs smoothly. How would I fix the first example? Am I doing something wrong with `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I fix the first example? Am I doing something wrong with `this`?

You can't. The object **is not yet created**, so you can't refer to the property, using `this`

You can however do this

```
var obj = {
    array: ['1.mp3', '2.mp3', '3.mp3'],
}; // object now created
obj.audio = new Audio(this.obj.array[0]); // set the property.
```

Note that you can refer to `this` to refer to the `obj` *inside* functions, but not outside them.

```
var obj = {
   prop: (console.log(this), "Some value") // most probably Window but never obj
   func: function(){
      console.log(this); // obj
   }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I've seen many examples of Javascript on the web with functions in an object referring to other functions in the object using `this` before object is finished defining. One such example is the source of audio.js: https://github.com/kolber/audiojs/blob/master/audiojs/audio.js

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification. Will accept when I can.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using `this` inside of a constructor: it's not referring to `obj`, it's referring to the new Audio object. You won't be able to reference it using `this` from inside the object like that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same thing would be as follows:

`var refArray = ['1.mp3', '2.mp3', '3.mp3'];
     var myObj = {
        array: ['1.mp3', '2.mp3', '3.mp3'],
        audio: new Audio(this.obj.array[0]);
    };`

This does the same thing as stated in other answers, but allows you to add the audio object (as a property to the myObj) while you are defining the myObj variable.